# Save date of modification

Tags: php, entity-framework, symfony

I have in my entity a field where I store a date.

I want that when a change is made to another entity, the field is updated with the date of the modification.

Entity where i have the field :

```
class Offers{
    ...
    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     */
    private $last_update;
    ...
}
```

Entity making the action that updates the field:

```
class OffersUser
{
    ...
    /**
     * @var \MyAppBundle\AppBundle\Entity\Offers
     */
    private $offers;

    public function setOffers(\MyAppBundle\AppBundle\Entity\Offers $offers = null){
        $this->offers = $offers;
        return $this;
    }

    ...
}
```

Could do so that when a change is made in offeruser , my field last_update the entity offers updated ?

I could use the method updatedAt generated symfony?

Answer (score 0):

You may use [doctrine lifecycle callbacks](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/events.html#lifecycle-callbacks) to achieve this.

In config file your entity, define `lifecycleCallbacks` section or use annotation `@PreUpdate` if you don't use yaml.

For example Resources/config/doctrine/Entity.orm.yml

```
lifecycleCallbacks:
    prePersist: [ prePersist ]
    preUpdate:  [ preUpdate ]
```

Entity/Entity.php

```
public function preUpdate()
{
    ...
    $this->setChanged(new \DateTime());
    ...
}
```

Comment: preUpdate function would go in the entity of the field that I want to upgrade , or in the entity where the action is carried out ?

Comment: @urreta17 all functions called in entities [lifeCycle events](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/events.html#lifecycle-events). The preUpdate event occurs before the database update operations to entity data. It is not called for a DQL UPDATE statement.